# Import GLTF with TresJS in Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm stuggling to import a gltf model with TresJS.

GLTFModel is working fine - useGLTF doesn't find my asset.

I'm totally new to nuxt and TresJS, so any help is appreciated.

I keep getting a "500 - Failed to parse URL from /figur.gltf"

Thanks

```
<script setup>
  import { OrbitControls, useGLTF, GLTFModel } from '@tresjs/cientos'
  const { scene, nodes, animations, materials } = await useGLTF('/figur.gltf', { draco: true })

<!-- useGLTF not working...  -->

</script>

<template>

  <TresCanvas
    window-size
    clear-color="#444444"
    shadows
    alpha
  >
    <TresPerspectiveCamera :position="[500, 500, 500]" :args="[45, 1, 0.1, 100000]"/>
    <OrbitControls />
    <TresAmbientLight :intensity="2" />
    <TresMesh>
      <TresTorusGeometry :args="[1, 0.5, 16, 32]" />
      <TresMeshBasicMaterial color="orange" />
    </TresMesh>
    <Suspense>
       <primitive :object=" nodes " />
       <!-- <GLTFModel path="/figur.gltf" draco />   Working -->
    </Suspense>
  </TresCanvas>
</template>
```

Comment: I just sent an MP to the main maintainer of Tres. In the meantime, feel free to join [the Discord](https://discord.gg/gjGrePgW3N) or open an issue on the repo if not already done.

Comment: Thank you, kissu. To be precise, useGLTF is actually from the cientos components, not tresjs. The examples provided seem to work, but I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: With the help of the great guys from the TresJS discord, I got my mistake:


 If you want to use await at the top level of the setup, the component will be wrapper in the suspense. This mean your file structure will be something like:
<TresCanvas >

...
  <Suspense>
   <MyComponentWithAwait />
  <\Suspense>

Now it works.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question.